# how to remove grub from bios without admin

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

I  messed up. my Ubuntu personal laptop had ran out of space and that made Ubuntu unbootable on it. so i installed Ubuntu on a flash drive using my school computer (not Ubuntu portable, i used the flash drive itself as a drive for normal Ubuntu install) and accidentally put grub on the bios. i have no access to the bios (because it is a school computer with a bios password) and i cannot use windows to remove it because that would require admin rights. i am not going to say anything to the STS because i don't want to get in trouble and also, it messed up the time in windows so it will say "5 pm" when it is actually 11:00 am and i cannot change it without admin rights (window 11).
any help? i need a command that i can run with "try Ubuntu" disk that i used to install Ubuntu in the first place. i can get into windows by spamming f12 on post and selecting windows boot manager. i just need to remove the grub thing labeled "ubuntu" from my boot devices. whenever i turn on my school computer it just puts it into the grub terminal and i have to type exit every time i try to get into windows. i am not sure how grub works but i don't think it is being stored on a drive or any partitions but is in the bios. but if i could add it to the bios without admin i can probably do the opposite.

Comment: Most probably it is possible to undo the changes you mmmade to the school computer accidentally. The bootloader itself is stored on a partition, (ESP), the EFI boot menu entry is stored in NVRAM, you'd have to delete both.I'll not give you further details about how to do that because you have the risk producing more "accidents" when something goes wrong during your repair attempts. The correct way is to inform the school staff.